# Difference in slide animation of header and footer

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

When I use a slide animation (in this case I used slideToggle), I noticed that there is a difference between sliding a header div and a footer div.

When sliding a footer, the content (in this case a h1) slides along nicely with the background. This is not the case with a header div. It seems that only the background is moving, while I would like the header to slide the same way as the footer does.

Please view the demo that I made on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/2/).
Thank you.

Comment: This is because the background is "anchored" to the top left by default. When the top moves down, the background moves with it. When the bottom closes up, the background stays attached to the top left. You can see this by putting a background image in place, and setting it's background-position to top or bottom.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use `.slideToggle()` which is convenient, you can animate the header element's `top` property so it slides off the screen rather than changing height.

For example you can save the state of the header using `.data()` and animate the header using `.animate()`:

```
//set the initial state and bind click event handler
$('#toggleHeader').data('state', 0).bind('click',function(){

    //if the header is showing
    if ($(this).data('state') === 0) {

        //set state to not showing
        $(this).data('state', 1);

        //animate header element out-of-view
        $('#header').stop(true).animate({ top : -102 });
    } else {

        //set state to showing
        $(this).data('state', 0);

        //animate header element into view
        $('#header').stop(true).animate({ top : 0 });
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/3/

Answer (score 2):

Jasper's fix does work but ThatSteveGuy's explanation is also correct. To fix the problem using ThatSteveGuy's reasoning and still keeping all of your old code, add this to the CSS:

```
#header h1 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  bottom:40px;
}
```

​as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/58/

Answer (score 2):

The toggle event is essentially a specialized click event. You can read the documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/toggle

So you can create a toggle animation like so:

```
$('#toggleHeader').toggle(function() {
    $('#header').animate({top: "-102px"});
    }, function() {
        $('#header').animate({top: "0px"});
    }
);
```

You can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/43/

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't know you can do this with jQuery toggle(). This one is my favorite...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to animate not height (default slideToggle behavior), but marginTop or top (with position relative or absolute).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggleHeader').bind('click',function(){
        $('#header').marginTopToggle();
    });       

    $('#toggleFooter').bind('click',function(){
        $('#footer').slideToggle();
    });        
});

$.fn.marginTopToggle = function(time) {
    time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[ time ] || time : time;        
    if(parseInt($(this).css("margin-top")) == 0) {
        $(this).animate({"margin-top": "-" + $(this).outerHeight() + "px"}, time );
    } else {
        $(this).animate({"margin-top": 0}, time );
    }
}
```

It is height-independent and works with standard jQuery speeds:

http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/13/

You can also position text in header relative to its bottom and that will work too.

http://jsfiddle.net/xhFz7/14/

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggleHeader').bind('click', function() {
        var header = $('#header'), //cached for repeated use
            height = header.outerHeight(),
            anims = {
                slideUp: function() {
                    header.stop().animate({'top': -(height) + 'px'}, 500, function() {
                        header.hide();
                    });
                },
                slideDown: function() {
                    header.stop().show().animate({'top': '0px'}, 500);
                }
            };
        (header.is(':visible')) ? anims.slideUp() : anims.slideDown();
    });

    $('#toggleFooter').bind('click', function() {
        $('#footer').slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HXD2G/1/

Answer (score 1):

**slideToggle** animates the *height* and sets *overflow* to *hidden*. The elements children (h1) are, as standard behaviour, positioned at the top of their parent. 
When the parent shrinks, they stay *at the top*, causing a different effect for header and footer.

By wrapping an extra block with a fixed height around the header's content, and positioning it from the **bottom** of the header, the content will go up when this box shrinks in height.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/2CSPR/